# How to optimize drawing a lot elements on canvas JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a lot of elements and mousemove method which, when selecting an item does redraw canvas.

```
function redraw(ctx) { // ctx - canvas context
    if (!needRedraw) 
        return;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    drawItems(ctx);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawItems(ctx) {
    var l = nodes.length(); // array of elements for drawing (from 100 to 100000)
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var item = nodes[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = colors(item.type);
        ctx.fillStyle = fill(item);
        ctx.arc(item.x, item.y, item.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

How to optimize this process, since it runs through all the elements of this highly expensive? 
May be used async method, but i'm not understand how to apply him?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calls to `save`, `restore` and `closePath` do nothing as they are written. Remove them.

`save` and `restore` copy alllll of the canvas state and should be rarely if ever used. In a perfect performant world the only reason you'll ever need to use them is to reset the clipping region.

Draw one and only one path, and fill (and stroke) it only once, at the end.

Like this:

```
function redraw(ctx) { // ctx - canvas context
    if (!needRedraw) 
        return;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    drawItems(ctx);
}

function drawItems(ctx) {
    var l = nodes.length(); // array of elements for drawing (from 100 to 100000)
    ctx.beginPath(); //outside of loop!
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var item = nodes[i];
        ctx.moveTo(item.x+item.r,item.y); // set up subpath to be at the right point
        ctx.arc(item.x, item.y, item.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    }
    ctx.fill();     //outside of loop!
    ctx.stroke();   //outside of loop!
}
```

Depending on what you're doing its very possible there are more optimizations to be had, but that should help!

Hope your project goes well.

Comment: Thanks for answer and nice words about my project =) But if i removed `ctx.beginPath` and another method, that you have learned outside of loop, then stroke and fill style of the last item to apply to all items . Yes, I gave the example of wrong!

Comment: just for the record : save and restore saves/restores only what has changed, on Chrome at last -it is faster to do save/restore than to do it by hand on more than 2 properties-

Answer (score 2):

There's a [great article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/) on optimizing canvas operations, many of which might apply to you.

Probably the easiest to start with is moving the `beginPath()` and `closePath()` calls out of your loop, and instead use `moveTo()` in between the segments, as well as drawing your canvas off screen and then copying it over to the display canvas.

Comment: Thanks for article! I'll try your suggestions!

Comment: This article was last updated about 3 years ago, and unfortunately many of the examples don't work anymore (although the content is still relevant). When I'm googling for performance tips on HTML5 Canvas this usually comes up first, and it always makes me a bit disappointed that nothing more recent comes up on top.

Answer (score 1):

You could also reverse your loop, assuming it's ok to draw everything in reverse order, as jsperf shows this to be quicker. A while loop is even quicker still.

**example**

```
var i = nodes.length();
while (i--) {
    // ...do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thx! Each tip can help my optimize project!

Answer (score 1):

Another performance tip: cache your Math.PI * 2 result.

As it is, javascript is getting `PI` from an object, then multiplying it. The value is always going to be the same so just add a constant

**example**

```
const PI_TIMES_TWO = 6.28; //or whatever degree of accuracy you want.

...

ctx.arc(item.x, item.y, item.r, 0, PI_TIMES_TWO, true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Why i didn't think about it =)